# Always show top nav bar in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010

SharePoint 2010 standard UI has the top nav bar which can have links added and (the more important part) the search field.

However when you use the ribbon to select an item or list, it moves off browse and takes the links and search away.

Anyway to configure it not to do that?

I know custom master page, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the ribbon behaviour can be overridden in a custom (alternatecss) css file. This might help you http://blog.drisgill.com/2010/01/sp2010-branding-tip-11-un-floating.html

Comment: You learn something new every day. I'd probably consider this over a custom masterpage. The same blog has a warning you should not when setting an alternate css >> http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-8-alternate-css-can.html

Comment: ah yeah i think that was a beta only issue

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Robert, but a custom masterpage is the way to do it.